# css to open details box on thumbnail hover or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, visible

I have been searching for a while but can't quite find what I'm looking for. Imagine a horizontal row of thumbnails: if the user either hovers or clicks one of them, a page-wide div opens above the line of thumbs to reveal such things as a larger image and/or text details of the selected item. If the user exits the hover or clicks outside of the thumbs-row, the detail box goes away.  Here is an image of the overall concept:

[image: illustration of this idea]

The following code is as far as I have gotten:

```
<style>
.item_container{float:left;  padding-left: 5px;}
.item_details {border:1px solid #000000;}
.hidden>div {
    display:none;
}

.visible>div {
    display:block;
}

</style>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item_container').addClass("hidden");

    $('.item_container').hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.hasClass("hidden")) {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="item_container">
         <div class="item_details">
<img src="images/item/One.jpg" `height="300px" id="pic" />Details for item One </div> <!--div that we want to hide-->` 


        <h3>One</h3>
</div><!--end div_item_container-->
<div class="item_container">
         <div class="item_details">
<img src="images/item/Two.jpg" height="300px"  id="pic" />Details for item Two</div> <!--div that we want to hide-->  
        <h3>Two</h3>
</div><!--end div_item_container-->
```

The problem is that the item_details divs open within the thumb/button div, rather than in a large box above the whole row.  I suspect this will involve using a distinct ID for each item div (which is fine...but I don't yet have the hang of how to do that).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I made a codepen of the code above: [link](http://codepen.io/phc_joe/pen/jWjoJa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ne57366v/2/

The suggestion is where you have thumbnail and info tags like:

```
<div id="info1" class="info">Info 1.</div>
<div id="thumbnail1" class="thumb"> Thumb 1. </div>
```

And then code to relate both of them like:

```
$(".thumb").mouseenter(function() {
  var id = this.id.slice(this.id.length - 1, this.id.length);
  id = "#info" + id;
    $(".info").each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $(id).show();
});
```

Sorry for the bad explanation but check the Fiddle to see it fully:

- You can click to view/unview the info.
- Hovering over allows you to view info.
- Hovering away hides info.

Comment: This is nearly perfect.  If I take the height/width dimensions out of the #infoHolder CSS, the area disappears when I have not selected anything.  Cannot get the code working outside jsfiddle...looking for typos now.

Comment: I am going to select this as the accepted answer because I understood the code well enough to modify it for my purpose. Thanks to you, and to everyone else for their suggestions!  I think I am going to try to modify it further to figure out how to click open and closed rather than relying on hover.

Comment: The lower right pane at jsfiddle is ok in Chrome but sadly 404 in Firefox v86 even with my popup add-on turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead by using attributes and passing values to update the information you wanted to display, something like this for example:

HTML

```
<div id="displayArea">
<img />
<div class="details"></div>
</div>


<div class="items">
  <div class="item" data-img="one.jpg" data-title="Details for item 1">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-img="two.jpg" data-title="Details for item number two">
    Two
  </div>
<div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#displayArea { max-height: 50px; height: 50px; border; 1px solid #000; }
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').hover(function() {
        $('#displayArea img').attr('src',$(this).attr('data-img'));
        $('#displayArea .details').html($(this).attr('data-title'));
        $('#displayArea img').show();
        $('#displayArea .details').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#displayArea img').hide();
        $('#displayArea .details').hide();
    });

});
```

If you wanted to run it on a click event instead, you could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.item').on('click',function() {
            $('#displayArea img').attr('src',$(this).attr('data-img'));
            $('#displayArea .details').html($(this).attr('data-title'));
     });
});
```

You can see an example of it here: https://jsfiddle.net/9rhLd86j/

Comment: Yes. This is on the right track.  I will try to play with your code for a while and see if the displayArea will completely disappear and/or resize appropriately based on the variable amount of content that will be available for each of the items.

Comment: @phc_joe that should be east to accomplish, you can add some CSS floating and positioning to change the positioning.  Hope that helps!

Comment: This is getting very close to what I need, but I think hover might be a bad way to do this (everything is bouncing, opening/closing with casual movements)  can the script be modified to click open/close.

Comment: @phc_joe of course, just use the click event instead of the hover event.  I updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

if you are curious of a CSS version and use of `li` items and `figure`/`figcaption`.

---

`tabindex` in HTML + `:focus` and `:hover` in CSS.

`padding` for the room of image + description, `flex` to easily spread items.

---

```css
.item_container ul {
  width: 640px;
  padding: 500px 10px 10px;
  border: solid;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  /* scary makeup */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 50%) no-repeat 10px 10px, linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat 10px 10px turquoise;
  background-size: 640px 480px;
}
.item_container {
  margin: 1em;
}
figure {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  ;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px, 0 0 0 1px white;
}
li > img {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
li:hover figure,
li:focus figure {
  display: block;
}
li:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
  background:white;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
/* set description else where ? */

li:nth-child(odd) figcaption {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
figure img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item_container">
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/1" alt="item 1" />Item 1
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/1" alt=" nature 1" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/2" alt="item 2" />Item 2
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/2" alt=" nature 2" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/3" alt="item 3" />Item 3
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/3" alt=" nature 3" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/4" alt="item 4" />Item 4
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/4" alt=" nature 4" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/5" alt="item 5" />Item 5
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/5" alt=" nature 5" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/6" alt="item 6" />Item 6
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/6" alt=" nature 6" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/7" alt="item 7" />Item 7
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/7" alt=" nature 7" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/nature/8" alt="item 8" />Item 8
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nature/8" alt=" nature 8" />
        <figcaption>
          items descriptions
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
</div>
<!--end div_item_container-->
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeJJMK?editors=1100

---

or 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyXeER?editors=1100 (wrapped if unhovered or clicked twice )

Comment: This is nice, but as is, it keeps the display area full open at all times (I would like it to shrink away if none of the items have been clicked, and permit the visitor to click the display area closed) and does not seem to adapt the display area to variable size contents.  As I barely know what I am doing with either CSS or JavaScript, I am always a fan of working with just one or the other to reduce my confusion.  This might be something I can use elsewhere though. Thanks!

Comment: @phc_joe if it is closed and shrinked by defaut, and items underneath, you may have some funny jumpy behavior http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyXeER?editors=1100 unless i totally misunderstood :)

Comment: Yes. I have encountered that with a couple of other "hover" models and it is indeed annoying.  I think the best would be for hover (or perhaps more correctly a mouseover event would open the full display, and moving to another item button would change the full display for that item.  "Mouseout" should probably NOT close the full display...there should maybe be a click button to accomplish that.

Comment: @phc_joe , full display could be underneath, overlaying other content like a folding menu does, or aside :)